# Switch in a Macro

Tags: macro, switch

I'm getting the following error:

Unexpected end of template. Twig was looking for the following tags "case", "default", or "endswitch" to close the "switch" block started at line 11)

Here is the contents of my _macros template:

```
{% set backgrounds = {
    white: { class: "white-bg", value: "White" },
    grey: { class: "grey-bg", value: "Grey" },
    black: { class: "black-bg", value: "Black" },
    highlight: { class: "highlight-bg", value: "Highlight" },
    base: { class: "base-bg", value: "Base" }
    }
%}

{% macro backgrounds(backgrounds, fieldName) %}
    {% switch fieldName %}
        {% for background in backgrounds %}
            {% case "{{ background.value }}" %}
                {{ background.class }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endswitch %}
{% endmacro %}
```

And here is my template that is throwing the error:

```
{% import '_macros' as siteMacros %}
<section class="content-35">
    <ul class="content-35-customPager">
        <li class="menuicon">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="fui-list"></span>
        </li>
        {% for slide in block.slides %}
        <li>
            <a {% if loop.first %}class="active"{% endif %} data-slide-index="{{ loop.index0 }}">
                {{ slide.slideTitle }}
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <ul class="content-35-slider">
        {% for slide in block.slides %}
            <li class="
            content-35-slider-item 
            {{ siteMacros.backgrounds(backgrounds, slide.backgroundColor ) }}
            ">
                <div class="background landscape">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div>
                                    {% for image in slide.slideImage %}
                                        <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" alt="">
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-5">
                            {% if slide.heading|length %}
                                <h2>
                                    {{ slide.heading }}
                                </h2>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if slide.intro|length %}
                                {{ slide.intro|replace({'<p>' : '<p class="lead">'})| raw }}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if slide.text|length %}
                                {{ slide.text }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</section>
```

The field slide.backgroundColor is a dropdown with all the values that are also listed in the Set for the backgrounds. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest a for loop within a `switch`, but outside of a `case`. Try this for brevity:

```
{% macro backgrounds(backgrounds, fieldName) %}
    {% for background in backgrounds %}
        {{ fieldName == background.value ? background.class : '' }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Also, your backgrounds array won't work sitting in the macro file. It needs to be either in the template, or included in from another template.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up realizing i was overcomplicating the entire thing and did not need a macro or a switch haha. Good to know for next time though!